# Matlab: Need to create a legend dynamically for plotted points

Tags: matlab, graph, legend

I have made a graph in Matlab which generates points and plots a red cross if the point is inside a specified box, and a blue circle if it is outside. The plotting works fine but the generation of the legend I have found tricky to get right. Just adding a legend at the end of the plotting only shows an entry corresponding to the last point plotted.

I eventually got it working using the code below, by creating a legend for the first point created then, when the other type of point was plotted, getting the current legend and appending the new points information into it.

This looks really long winded, is there a better way of generating a legend for this way of plotting points?

```
figure;
title('A Graph') ;
hold on;
redhandle = 0
bluehandle = 0
redlegendmade = 0;
bluelegendmade = 0;
for count1 = 1:100
  % Get a random point in a circle with radius 5
  random_radius = sqrt(5)*rand(); 
  random_angle = 2*pi*rand; 

  % Set x and y coordinates. 
  x = random_radius*cos(random_angle); 
  y = random_radius*sin(random_angle); 

  % If point inside a box,centred on 0,0 with width = 4 and 
  % height = 2, draw a red cross, otherwise a blue circle.
  if (abs(x)< 2 && abs(y)<1) 
    % Get a handle to a plotted red point for legend
    redhandle = plot(x,y,'rx');

    % Actually plot the red point so its visible
    plot(x,y,'rx');

    % If we haven't already handled the red info for the legend, do so
    if (redlegendmade == 0)
      % Get current legend
      [LEGH,OBJH,OUTH,OUTM] = legend;

      % Update legend with red info
      legend([OUTH;redhandle],OUTM{:},'In')

      % Don't handle red info again
      redlegendmade = 1;
    end
    hold on;
  else
    % Get handle to plotted blue point for adding to legend
    bluehandle = plot(x,y,'bo');

    % Actually plot the blue point so it's visible
    plot(x,y,'bo');

    % If we havent already handled the blue info for legend, do so
    if (bluelegendmade == 0)
      % Get current legend
      [LEGH,OBJH,OUTH,OUTM] = legend;

      % Update legend with blue info
      legend([OUTH;bluehandle],OUTM{:},'Out')

      % Don't handle blue info again
      bluelegendmade = 1
    end
    hold on;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a legend handle for each of your point, and then use only the first and last one.

```
figure;
hold on;
for ii = 1:10
    if ii<5
        h(ii,1) = plot(rand,rand,'rx');
    else
        h(ii,1) = plot(rand,rand,'bo');
    end
end
legend([h(1) h(end)],{'red', 'blue'})
```

You may change the `1`and `end` index depending on the order the points are plotted.